# Macbook air 2017 not sleeping properly after upgrade to nvme ssd

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, sleep-wake

I was running very low on storage on my early 2017 model MacBook Air, so I followed this [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Early+2017+SSD+Upgrade+to+NVMe/121102) to try to upgrade my drive.

Unfortunately, it's been a few days, and I'm still experiencing an issue where upon opening the lid after sleep, I am greeted by a near-black screen, and have to hard shutoff and power on again (as well as log in) to start the computer (this also does not preserve my session). I have gotten a few different error messages seemingly randomly when I boot back up, one with a kernel stacktrace and one about a sleep wake failure. Both are pasted in links below.  There's also one about a "kernel panic" but I wasn't able to reproduce it -- will paste if I get it.

I have tried the suggested fix in the iFixit guide, which is turning off hibernation, but that did not work. I have also tried to adjust the standby timer or turn off standby, which also did not work. Finally, I unchecked "put hard disks to sleep when possible" in Energy Saver settings.

Does anyone have any ideas for something else to try?

Error message -- sleep wake failure: https://justpaste.it/6avh0

Error message -- other: https://justpaste.it/4x86v .

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error in retina macbooks when upgrading the SSD, and there is no solution. What do you mean that turning off hibernation didn't work? So after turning off hibernation, your computer still goes into standby mode?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell whether it's in standby mode, but it's the same issue in that I close the lid, the computer seemingly sleeps, and when I open it again the screen is black.

Comment: I see, I don't think you can disable sleep on lid close... Another solution you can try is an addon that disables sleep mode such as insomniax. https://insomniax.en.softonic.com/mac It has an option to disable sleep when the lid is closed. But you will need to be very careful about it overheating.